# How to send a mail without having to wait for the operation to complete

Tags: php, email, yii, sendmail

Inside my Yii 1.1 app i need to send 2 emails after a record is correctly created, but since the email function is slow (i'm using SMTP authentication) the user will have to wait 4-6 seconds every time.
I tried using php exec functions, but the script i call doesn't have the Yii framework.
Is there a way to just call an action or a mail function without having to wait?
The runaction Yii extension doesn't work for me, i tried to use it but the runBackground function is never fired.

Comment: Create a message queue. Yii has something called Mail Queue

Answer (score 1):

Hi I understand your requirement, You know Yii is highly inspired from Ruby on Rails. In Ruby on Rails, there is a `Delayed Job` . Fortunately Yii has some extention, for background jobs, Please look in to this,

[Yii Delayed Job](https://github.com/rolies106/yii-resque)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to a scheduler (like `cron`) on the server? Save messages to a queue processed non-interactively every minute.

Comment: My problem is i don't know if i'll have access to the server crons

Comment: External server can call the script automatically through HTTP. I wouldn't call this solution most reliable, take it as a last resort.